# Why using a pointer of a self-defined structure in the CS50 Inheritance problem

Tags: pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, cs50

Hi here is the [link of the homework description](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2024/psets/5/inheritance/). And here is the part of the code that's relevant:

```
typedef struct person
{
struct person *parents[2];
char alleles[2];
} person;

const int GENERATIONS = 3;

person *create_family(int generations);
void print_family(person *p, int generation);
void free_family(person *p);
char random_allele();
```

Please help me understand why we want the return value of`create_family(int generations)` to be a pointer, not just a variable person. What's the advantage of using pointer here?

I speculate that's because it's more efficient, as we can free the memory as we go, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The "usual and customary" answer here is that often times functions that are creating things such as structures will perform the necessary memory allocation within the function (for example, use "malloc").  Then, in order to let the statement in the program that called the creation function know where that memory is located, the reference to that memory is returned or passed back via the memory's address pointer.  One cannot pass back the structure name as that structure name is local to the function and no longer exists once a return is done from the function.

Comment: @NoDakker thanks for your answer! By **one cannot pass back the structure name as that structure name is local to the function and no longer exists once a return is done from the function**, do you mean that if the return value is a local variable existing on stack, instead of heap, it won't be accessible in `main` or other functions, as it will disappear once that specific function is finished?